# javascript - More accurate value of Pi?

Tags: javascript, math, pi

I type `Math.PI;` in Chrome Console and this is returned:

> 3.141592653589793

Then I type `Math.PI - 3.141592653589793;` and `0` was returned.

Is there a way to get a more accurate value (such as `3.1415926535897932384`) of `Math.PI` in Javascript?

Comment: Probably not. You can try to calculate pi yourself.

Comment: Here's a megabyte of pi, help yourself: http://newton.ex.ac.uk/research/qsystems/collabs/pi/pi6.txt But seriously, what are you trying to accomplish that 15 decimal places are not sufficient? Note that rounding errors at this scale are significant.

Comment: ["Seriously, it does make sense to define "pi" as a defined constant - not because it changes, but because it's tricky to determine the proper source code representation that will give the most accurate value for the number. That's why Java and JavaScript have Math.PI and Math.E final member variables..."](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueOfPi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum decimal places in javascript is limited to `15`.

So you cannot get more than 15 decimal places.

But you can get up to 20 decimal places by doing but its not accurate

```
Math.PI.toFixed(20); //3.14159265358979311600
```

That will give you a PI value with 20 decimal places.

**Note:** `20` is the maximum and `0` is the minimum for `toFixed()`.

So trying `Math.PI.toFixed(100)` will throw an error.

Comment: Yes, one can get 20 decimal places, but `11600` is not part of PI.

Comment: IEEE754 doubles aren't always rounded to 15 decimal places, that's misleading.

Comment: Actually, it is believed that 11600 shows up infinitely often in pie. Just not in that location. :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why you would need PI to such accuracy but you can either :

a) Calculate PI yourself using [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_pi)

b) Define PI yourself (using [this](https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js) library)

```
var PI = new bigdecimal.BigDecimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279");
```

You can find first 100,000 digits of PI [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~huberty/math5337/groupe/digits.html) if you really need it.

Comment: Option (b) does not work for me: `alert (PI == Math.PI);` returns `true`, while you assert it should *not* be the same.

Comment: One can say `var my_pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647;` etc. , but end-result will still be dependent on max precision on floating numbers. Typically `alert(my_pi);` will yield `3.141592653589793`. If one want more decimals one need to use an array. But then again it won't be *"of Math.PI"* as OP asks.

Comment: That will still not give you higher precision. `3141592653589793238462643383279/10` will only be accurate to `3.141592653589793` due to floating number limitation.

Comment: Sorry, quite new to this. Forgive me if its still wrong :p

Comment: "BigDecimal for Javascript is a pure-Javascript implementation of immutable, arbitrary-precision, signed decimal numbers."